# Extend Existing Docker Image

Tags: docker, teamcity, dockerfile

I've pulled the teamcity-agent image from:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/

I've installed Subversion and Node on top of this image and commited it back to Docker Hub by editing the existing image -

https://hub.docker.com/r/antonrand/teamcity-agent/

Now I'd like to extend the image - just by adding another mount point. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM antonrand/teamcity-agent

# Create build directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/test

VOLUME /usr/src/test

WORKDIR /usr/src/test
```

When I run this nothing happens, how can I tell Docker to run the CMD command which is already set up in the official image? They haven't published their Dockerfile so I don't know what to run.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have not published their Dockerfile, but you can reverse engineer it with https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image

At the very least, a `docker history teamcity-agent` should show it

Comment: I get `$ docker history jetbrains/teamcity-agent | grep CMD
<missing>           2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/run-services.sh"]      0 B                 
<missing>           7 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["java" "-version"]       0 B                 
<missing>           10 weeks ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B   `

Comment: I think only this line is relevant `CMD ["/run-services.sh"]`

Comment: Thank you, was just missing the CMD ["/run-services.sh"] line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming neither of your Docker additions changed the CMD or ENTRYPOINT of the image, you should be able to execute it the same way as the original teamcity image. The command is shown in their documentation on DockerHub:

```
docker run -it -e SERVER_URL="<url to TeamCity server>"  \ 
-v <path to agent config folder>:/data/teamcity_agent/conf  \      
<new-image-name>
```

where *new-image-name* is the new docker image you created with your second Dockerfile.